# Use Roslyn to get return statements ignoring the ones inside lambda expressions

Tags: c#, return, roslyn

I am trying to use roslyn to get the return statements of a method, for that I am using this:

```
var returns = methods.DescendantNodes().OfType<ReturnStatementSyntax>();
```

That works, it gives me all the return statements. But now, I want to get all the returns ignoring the ones inside lambda expressions.

How can I do that?

Is there any property that indicates that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure but you can try something similar like this:

```
method.DescendantNodes().OfType<ReturnStatementSyntax>().Where(
     rs => !(rs.AncestorsAndSelf().OfType<LambdaExpressionSyntax>().Any())
);
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: It would be much more efficient to write a visitor that never enters lambdas.